# tf.keras model.fit(): enormous difference between train loss and val loss on the same data

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

Tensorflow version 2.1

See the colab notebook to reproduce the issue: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fvc6G_9v5mek015cai7qYT6HoY-fLkzk/view?usp=sharing

When the training loss goes down the val_loss does not change, although this is exactly the same data.

> Train on 2 samples, validate on 2 samples
>   Epoch 1/30 2/2 [==============================] - 3s - 2s/sample - loss: 0.4630 - val_loss: 302.4763
>   Epoch 2/30 2/2 [==============================] -1s - 457ms/sample - loss: 0.8565 - val_loss: 496.9578
>   Epoch 3/30 2/2 [==============================] - 1s - 457ms/sample - loss: 0.7886 - val_loss: 1050.9148
>   Epoch 4/30 2/2 [==============================] - 1s - 450ms/sample - loss: 0.1080 - val_loss: 744.4895
>   Epoch 5/30 2/2 [==============================] - 1s - 474ms/sample - loss: 0.1144 - val_loss: 1353.2678
>   Epoch 6/30 2/2 [==============================] - 1s - 465ms/sample - loss: 0.0402 - val_loss: 3237.9683
>   Epoch 7/30 2/2 [==============================] - 1s - 465ms/sample - loss: 0.0635 - val_loss: 3946.7822
>   Epoch 8/30 2/2 [==============================] - 1s - 470ms/sample - loss: 0.0355 - val_loss: 4054.5461
>   Epoch 9/30 2/2 [==============================] - 1s - 462ms/sample - loss: 0.0345 - val_loss: 4991.5400

How is this possible?
The code is pretty straightforward:

```
ResNet18, preprocess_input = Classifiers.get('resnet18')
base_model = ResNet18(input_shape=(180, 320, 3), weights=None, include_top=False)
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output)
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(8)(x)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
data = np.random.rand(2, 180, 320, 3)
labels = np.random.rand(2, 8)

model.fit(data, labels, validation_data=(data,labels), batch_size=2, epochs=30)
```

There are known issues with keras and batch normalization (see for example keras-team/keras#6977). This is probably related, but I don't see directly how. What do I have to change to make this working as expected? Is this something in the included package https://github.com/qubvel/classification_models or where to solve it?

Edit: the behaviour of batch normalization is changed as of TF 2.0, so the other issues might not be related, see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/BatchNormalization

Answer (score 0):

You didn't preprocess your data to the range expected by the model. 
This model contains `BatchNormalization`, so you cannot use data that is not in the correct range.

You need to use `preprocess_input` in all your data, and of course, your initial range should be 0 to 255, as it's for images.

Ideally, you should use actual images, so you have a similar distribution.

Comment: I understand what you are saying,  but adding data = preprocess_input(data) does not solve this. preprocess_input is defined as def preprocess_input(x, **kwargs):
    return x so it does not do anything

Comment: @Derk,  Is `x` within 0 and 255?? It seems it's 0 and 1 by your code

Comment: I can use data = np.random.randint(255, size=(2, 180, 320, 3)) but that is not changing the issue

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether that is exactly what goes 'wrong' in your code, but commonly the behavior changes for models between Training and Evaluation mode. That affects, for example, [dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dropout). This can at least explain part of the difference in your outcomes.